# Value in Carry Flag

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

If I do the following (where `cx` has 0b1011 or 11 in decimal prior to the shift):

```
 shl cx, 1
```

After `shl`, the carry flag should be set. As `shl` will move 0b1011 to 0b0110 and 1 will be in `CF`.

My question is: how do I access the value in the carry flag? Let's say I want to append it to register `bx`, obviously `mov bx, cf` does not work so how would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what "add-with-carry" is for:

```
adc bx, 0   ; adds "0" plus the value of CF to bx
```

If you want to *set* a (byte) register exactly equal to the value of the carry flag, use "set-if-carry":

```
setc bl     ; BL = CF ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Thanks, one additional question. Is there a way to change the carry flag? As in how can I purposely set it to 1 or 0?

Comment: @user3211189: Yes, `stc` and `clc`.

Comment: Aso `cmc` - complement carry flag.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `JC` and `JNC` conditional branching instructions to determine if the flag is set or not.

There is also the `PUSHFD` instructions to dump the entire `EFLAGS` to the stack.